# Is there a Microsoft Publisher equivalent for LMDE?

Tags: debian, linux-mint

I am running Linux Mint Debian Edition (LMDE) and I need a program like Microsoft Publisher that I can make fliers and pamphlets with. Is there a program like that available? Is it free?

Comment: Have you looked at OpenOffice/LibreOffice Writer, I have succesfully made fliers with that, but I have no clue about what Microsoft Publisher can do? On Linux you might have to combine functionality from multiple programs. MS' software tended (back in the 90s) to suffer from featuritis, resulting in any user using less than 5% of the capabilities of the software. If that is the same for Publisher, it will be difficult for someone to answer, unless you indicate more specifically what kind of functionality you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus) is an open-source desktop publishing program and the closest analogue to Publisher. It supports importing Publisher files in the development branch (that is, the next major release).

[LibreOffice Draw](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/draw/) is also comparable. Its focus is as more of a vector graphics editor than a DTP tool, but it does have many DTP features too. It also supports Publisher import.

Both of these are in the LMDE repositories. Both of them are free.